# Getting an error coding in Perl when I'm try to use a DBI to use SQlite

Tags: sql, perl, sqlite

I'm trying to run this block of code and I'm getting this error:

> DBI connect('dbname=C:\Users\pdk11.UFAD\Desktop\RA\sap_populate','',...) failed: unable to open database file(1) at dbdimp.c line 94 at C:\Users\pdk11.UFAD\Desktop\RA\Perl\Extract items\04createheader_SAP_pk.pl line 41.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use HTML::Scrubber;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use HTML::FormatText;
use DBI;
use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday);
# Creates a table that holds heading information from Edgar 10-K Files.

$total1=gettimeofday;

#First specify the directory containing the files you want to get.
#use random sort, a file containing 10 files
$directory="D:\\ExternalFiles\\Edgar\\tenks\\";
#if windows, slash is "\\", mac "/";
$slash="\\";

#Connect to database
#$DSN is data source name
#$DSN='dbi:SQLite:dbname=A:\\MyFiles\\MyPapers\\Differential_Contagion\\Analysis\\Input\\acctgchanges.sqlite';
$DSN='dbi:SQLite:dbname=C:\\Users\\pdk11.UFAD\\Desktop\\RA\\sap_populate';
$use='';$pword='';
#connect to the sqlite database
$dbh=DBI->connect($DSN,$use,$pword,{RaiseError=>1, AutoCommit=>1});
```

[image: I've attached a picture of the SQL files that I've downloaded onto my hard drive.]

Comment: I've edited your question to display the image in line, but it looks like it's a broken link

Comment: You need a *lot* more white space to make your code readable. And `use strict` is mandatory.

Comment: It looks like you are not familiar enough with computers let alone programming. You are trying to do something by editing some script you found somewhere, but that is bound to end in disappointment.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $DSN='dbi:SQLite:dbname=C:\\Users\\pdk11.UFAD\\Desktop\\RA\\sap_populate';
> ```

It looks to me like `C:\Users\pdk11.UFAD\Desktop\RA\sap_populate` is a directory. You need to specify a database file in that directory.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I know I'm a little slow with this but I appreciate it. I'm not sure if you can see the picture I originally submitted but does it make sense to put those sqlite files in the "sap_populate" file and then run it?

When you say I need to specify a database file can you walk me through what that means slowly? Thank you again.

Comment: The answer is no. SO is not a free one-on-one tutoring service. You lack the knowledge and skills to accomplish this task at this point in time.